# unable to connect to sql server through vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

i added the bindingsource control on my winform. here are the details of my connection:

http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/3797/42119312.jpg

when i test the connection, it says "the connection cannot be tested because the specified DB file does not exist"

the DB is located in http://sql0234mjf-2.ordfsweb.com. how should i set up bindingsource?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219472/how-do-i-connect-to-a-remote-sql-server-2005-db-through-vb-net

Comment: Did you just revealed the real name of an Internet accessible SQL instance on a public forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong provider. The "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" provider is not the SQL Server provider. Is the provider for [user instances attached files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564(SQL.90).aspx) (RANU). User instances are a SQL Express edition only feature and they can only be accessed locally.

To connect to a true SQL Server instance you need to use the proper provider, the [Data Provider for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb9s9ks0(VS.80).aspx). When you choose this provider you are presented with a different dialog that ahs options to specify the server name and database name.

Comment: this is good but which control handles sql server? can you please be more specific on what i should do

Comment: When you define the connection in you project you should choose the proper provider in the very first step. Or define the connection in code and use SqlConnectionStringBuilder class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Comment: can you be more specific please on where and how i can choose the provider?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like you're trying to use a database file instead of a database server, you may need to modify your data source.